# Avoid shell printing output when running in params directive

Tags: shell, snakemake

I have a rule approximately structured as

```
rule something:
    input: "file1.txt"
    output: "file2.txt"
    params: my_variable = shell("uname")
    shell: "cat <({params.my_variable}) {input} > {output}"
```

This causes my workflow to print out the output of `my_variable` right before

```
Linux
Building DAG of jobs...
```

etc.

This messes up with a series of options in Snakemake, though (e.g., `snakemake -R $(snakemake --list-code-changes)` or `snakemake --dag | dot`) and forces to sanitise the output of the `snakemake` call (e.g. `snakemake --dag | grep <(uname) -v | dot`). Is there a way to prevent this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

```
params:
    my_variable=os.uname().sysname
```

`my_variable=shell(...)` probably doesn't do what you need anyway because it just executes the shell command and the variable `my_variable` stays empty (`None`)

Comment: In my original script, I have a `cat` command, the `uname` is for the example

Comment: `my_variable` is going to be `None` so I don't see much use of  `{params.my_variable}`. My feeling is that you should either replace `shell(some_cmd)` with python code or move the shell command `some_cmd` inside the shell directive or add a dedicated rule for running `some_cmd`.